# Initialising std::array problems

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have a piece of code that looks like this

```
#define PINS 40
#include <array>

class test {
    typedef void (*fptr_t)();
    template<int PIN>
    void interrupt_cb_t() {}

    std::array<fptr_t, PINS> interruptTable =
    {
        interrupt_cb_t<0>, interrupt_cb_t<1>, interrupt_cb_t<2>, interrupt_cb_t<3>, interrupt_cb_t<4>,
        interrupt_cb_t<5>, interrupt_cb_t<6>, interrupt_cb_t<7>, interrupt_cb_t<8>, interrupt_cb_t<9>,
        interrupt_cb_t<10>, interrupt_cb_t<11>, interrupt_cb_t<12>, interrupt_cb_t<13>, interrupt_cb_t<14>,
        interrupt_cb_t<15>, interrupt_cb_t<16>, interrupt_cb_t<17>, interrupt_cb_t<18>, interrupt_cb_t<19>,
        interrupt_cb_t<20>, interrupt_cb_t<21>, interrupt_cb_t<22>, interrupt_cb_t<23>, interrupt_cb_t<24>,
        interrupt_cb_t<25>, interrupt_cb_t<26>, interrupt_cb_t<27>, interrupt_cb_t<28>, interrupt_cb_t<29>,
        interrupt_cb_t<30>, interrupt_cb_t<31>, interrupt_cb_t<32>, interrupt_cb_t<33>, interrupt_cb_t<34>,
        interrupt_cb_t<35>, interrupt_cb_t<36>, interrupt_cb_t<37>, interrupt_cb_t<38>, interrupt_cb_t<39>
    };
};
```

however when compiling with 'g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp' I get two errors:

'test.cpp:22:5: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
     };'

and

'test.cpp:22:5: error: too many initializers for ‘std::array’'

but I don't understand why I am getting these when I have both a brace enclosed initialiser list and exactly the right amount of elements in the list?

Comment: `interrupt_cb_t` is a member function where as `fptr_t` is a non-member function pointer.

Comment: tldr, use double `{{` and `}}`